# .NET Directory.Move results in Access to path is denied with network paths

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, file, io

I know there are a bunch of these questions already but none of the ones I found depict the scenario I have.

So what I want to do is to
move a directory via Directory.Move. Both source and destination are on a file server in the same network so both paths are network paths (starting with \\SERVER rather than a drive letter).

The application that‘s supposed to do that gives me an „UnauthorizedException: Access is denied“. Because it‘s confidential I can‘t show the log or code.

But I tried to reproduce it by simply calling Directory.Move via PowerShell ([System.IO.Directory]::Move()). There I receive the same message. Access to path X is denied. Nothing more.

This error appears with any user context. An admin, an admin with „run as admin“, the user of the application and the user of the application with „run as admin“.

Manually moving these directories works without a problem.

Creating a directory with Directory.CreateDirectory works too. But moving the newly created Directory results in the same error.

Executing these commands on the file server works just fine if using the local path. Using the network path (still on the actual fileserver, though) results again in the Acces is denied error.

Could it be, that the issue lies within the path rather than the directory? The permissions are all correct and set (as said, manual operations work). Are there any workarounds?

I really don‘t know what to do. I‘m the only developer at this company and the rest are network engineers and can‘t help
me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things that could be causing it to deny access and it would be hard to point you in the right direction without seeing your code. But here are 2 scenarios that might help you.

Scenario 1 - The filepath you are using is in the wrong format, Usually I have had a access denied because the format of the network filepath was actually wrong. I would recommend looking up examples of how you should pass the filepath. Also have a talk with your network engineers and ask them about the rights that have been setup for that filepath.

Scenario 2 - You might be passing a filepath when you also need to specify a name. Now I dont have all the details but I also had issues in the past using the Directory.Move function where I actually had to specify a filename to move it to. You do this by just adding the file and extension to the end of the target path to copy to.

If you could post some more information I might be able to point you in the right direction but this is what I can think of for now. I hope this works for you or atleast brings you closer to an answer. Good luck!

*Edit: It looks like I am wrong on the scenarios, Have a look at this link [Can you move a file/folder across a network share in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646938/can-you-move-a-file-folder-across-a-network-share-in-net)

You will have to first manually create the filepath and then copy all the files into the new filepath you have created. It seems like Directory.Move has problems when different machines are used.

Comment: For Scenario 1: I‘m 100% confident the path is correct. I can paste it in the File Explorer and the correct folder is opened. And using that path for Directory.Create works as well. And I saw the permissions for the directory and they are correct. As for Scenario 2: There is no file in the directory. And even if, I want to move the entire directory, not just a file.

Comment: Sorry I had to edit my post. Have a look at the answer in my link. It looks like you cant do a Directory.Move when two different machines are available. You will have to 1.Check if the target filepath exists, If no then create it. 2. Copy the files over to the newly created file. You will basically have to write your own Directory.Move method

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Manually moving the files, that is. But it‘s a problem because the application is simply not programmed to do that. And an update always requires a new license, contract and bla bla. Stuff done overly complicated and only once a year. My boss is gonna be so mad… But thank you for the answer. The edit was the solution.